# create new table with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have create `controller`, `model` and `view` using scaffold with attributes:

`org_name, org_description, webdomain, offc_addr, offc_ph`

and my problem is that i want to create multiple **address** against single **organization** and multiple **phone numbers** against single **address**.

I am not confirm to use the following command

`rails generate migration NAME [field:type field:type] [options]`

as i just want to create a table and create association with other table not interested in creating **View** for that table and *i am using nested form*.

So please tell me whether is this appropriate or I do something else... Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting anything I given below you must remove any tables or controllers you created before and start it as a new and follow the instructions given below to avoid any exceptions or duplications.

So first you would need to generate a scaffold for Organizations and a simple model for PhoneNumbers and Addresses (this will generate its migration as well to add tables). Now reason for generating scaffold for Organiztaions only is because you would not need forms (views) for PhoneNumbers or Addresses. But you would be relating addresses to some organization and phone_numbers to some address so that will be handled through code later and I will explain you to keep it simple and make sure its working. Now first you would need to run the following commands:

```
rails generate scaffold organizations org_name:string org_description:text webdomain:string

rails generate model address offc_addr:text organization_id:integer

rails generate model phone_number offc_ph:string address_id:integer
```

Now this will generate all you require. Next you would need to run the following command to add tables in database.

```
rake db:migrate
```

Once you are done with that you would need to tweak your models as mentioned below:

```
#FOR ORGANIZATIONS
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :org_description, :org_name, :webdomain
  has_many :addresses

  #THIS IS TO MAKE IT EASIER TO MANAGE IT IN VIEWS (read about nested attributes if you do not know)
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses

end

#FOR ADDRESS
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :offc_addr, :organization_id
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :phone_numbers

  #THIS IS TO MAKE IT EASIER TO MANAGE IT IN VIEWS (read about nested attributes if you do not know)
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers

end

#FOR PHONE NUMBER
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address_id, :offc_ph
  belongs_to :address
end
```

Thats all your required to do. Now just generate fields_for addresses using organization object and fields_for phone_numbers using address object in your views. For your help you can read nested_attributes behaviour from the link below:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

I hope this will help you Wasi and will clear things for you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
rails generate migration
```

Will only create a migration file, no view or controller. This is a good way to add new tables or new fields to your db schema.

Comment: No, I don't want to add new fields.. I am interesting in creating a new whole table that has association with other table and not want any view controller for that table.

Answer (score 0):

You need a model:

```
rails generate model address organization_id:integer, street:string zip:string city:string //etc
```

This will generate an `address.rb` in the models folder and a database migration.

Then migrate the database:

```
rails db:migrate
```

and you'll have the table in the database.

Then you'll need to look into `belongs_to` and `has_many` etc for tying them together in your code.

Comment: Ok thats fine. But what if i want to use a foreign key in the table as u created in above command??

Comment: Either list it in the `rails generate...` command, or if you already have generated it, add it with a migration: `rails generate migration addPhoneIdToAddress`. Remember to edit the generated migration to fill out any blanks and then run `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create three table for it, org, address and phone.
Then make relationship with them.

First table is the table you have created, remove the address and phone line.
**org_name, org_description, webdomain**

Second table is address.
**offc_addr, org_id**

Third table is phone address.
**offc_phone, org_phone_id**

Then change the model.
Org has_many offc_addr and offc_addr has_many offc_phone

Comment: Second table is adress. **offc_addr, org_id** thats fine.
but i didn't understand _third table is phone address. **offc_phone, org_phone_id** what if i used **offC_phone, offc_addr_id** instead???

Comment: address belongs_to organization, phone belongs_to address.

Comment: organization_address = organization.address   organization_phone = organizaion.address.phone